# Utilizing Django url resolver vs. re-inventing the request.path parsing wheel

Tags: django

Let's say I had the following array:

```
sub_urls = [
   '/',
   '/<uuid:id>',
   '/test',
   '/test/<uuid:id>'
]
```

The URL stings are very similar to what you'd find in Django's `urlpatterns`

my question:

can `django.url.resolve` be used to find the pattern in the `sub_urls` array given a path string like `/test/189e8140-e587-4d5d-ac5c-517fd55c67bc` without me having to re-invent the wheel here?

PLEASES NOTE: this isn't a question about how I route from urls to views in Django. Please don't tell me how to "solve it with `urlpatterns`, `re_path` etc." This is about utilizing this same mechanism by which django matches up a URL with a view --- for a COMPLETELY different purpose. I can write this myself, but I wanted to know if there's a way to re-use what Django has as it CLEARLY has the same needs when parsing `request.path` into the correct view.

Comment: What about the [`re_path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#re-path) ?

Comment: My purpose isn’t analyzing urls to convert to views. It’s the mechanism I’m interested it, for a completely different purpose.

Comment: Seems like `resolve()` is tightly coupled with `settings.ROOT_URLCONF`. You can pass it a "urlconf" argument but it looks for a cached value. So most likely the answer seems no. If it's just "I want to match a string to a pattern" then using python's `re` module directly seems like a good approach. See: https://github.com/django/django/blob/c70cd2a926ffab47f6613e83e0c8828eb6c2c064/django/urls/base.py#L21 and https://github.com/django/django/blob/c70cd2a926ffab47f6613e83e0c8828eb6c2c064/django/urls/resolvers.py#L68

Comment: First of all, I am not sure what is your ***"exact use-case"***, but, If I want to *"match certain strings"* I would go for Python's `re` module, provided there are no view functions (call back functions) are involved. The Django resolver is also built on top of the `re` module with some extra logic and (personally) I won't choose Django to resolve some regex patterns.

Comment: It is kinda important to know where and how you want to use it. Because the request object contains a resolver property that basically is the result record of the resolve operation. This can for instance be used to more strictly validate path components or match paths to (openapi) specs to validate request payload and response codes. So you may not have to run anything, but just access the [ResolverMatch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.resolver_match) instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [`django.urls.resolve`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c70cd2a926ffab47f6613e83e0c8828eb6c2c064/django/urls/base.py#L21-L24) calls [`get_resolver`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c70cd2a926ffab47f6613e83e0c8828eb6c2c064/django/urls/resolvers.py#L68-L76) which creates a [`URLResolver`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5fcfe5361e5b8c9738b1ee4c1e9a6f293a7dda40/django/urls/resolvers.py#L379) (through `_get_cached_resolver`), you can instead create a `URLResolver` yourself:

```
# Define an empty view
def empty_view(*args, **kwargs):
    return None

# Define the urlpatterns
from django.urls import path
sub_urls = [
   '/',
   '/<uuid:id>',
   '/test',
   '/test/<uuid:id>'
]
urlpatterns = [path(u, empty_view) for u in sub_urls]

# Create a resolver
from django.urls.resolvers import URLResolver, RegexPattern
resolver = URLResolver(RegexPattern(r'^'), urlpatterns)

# Match a path
# Returns a django.urls.resolvers.ResolverMatch object
result = resolver.resolve('/test/189e8140-e587-4d5d-ac5c-517fd55c67bc')
print(result)
print(result.route)
```

The above code will output:

```
ResolverMatch(func=__main__.empty_view, args=(), kwargs={'id': UUID('189e8140-e587-4d5d-ac5c-517fd55c67bc')}, url_name=None, app_names=[], namespaces=[], route=/test/<uuid:id>)
/test/<uuid:id>
```

If you're set on using `django.urls.resolve`, you could move `urlpatterns` to a module, let's say `my_urls`:

```
# Define an empty view
def empty_view(*args, **kwargs):
    return None

# Define the urlpatterns
from django.urls import path
sub_urls = [
   '',
   '<uuid:id>',
   'test',
   'test/<uuid:id>'
]
urlpatterns = [path(u, empty_view) for u in sub_urls]
```

Notice we had to remove the `/` suffixes from the URLs above because [`_get_cached_resolver`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c70cd2a926ffab47f6613e83e0c8828eb6c2c064/django/urls/resolvers.py#L74-L76) creates a `RegexPattern` that starts with `/`.

And then pass the module name as the second argument to `resolve`:

```
# Configure settings (only needed when this is not being run in an existing Django app)
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()

# Match a path
# Returns a django.urls.resolvers.ResolverMatch object
from django.urls import resolve
result = resolve('/test/189e8140-e587-4d5d-ac5c-517fd55c67bc', urlconf='my_urls')
print(result)
print(result.route)
```

I don't believe the caching of [`_get_cached_resolver`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c70cd2a926ffab47f6613e83e0c8828eb6c2c064/django/urls/resolvers.py#L74-L76) should be an issue as @Clepsyd mentioned since [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=lru_cache#functools.lru_cache) caches depending on the arguments it receives.

Comment: Thank you. This is just what I needed.